# package (need URDF file) for ABB IRB4600-60/2.05? OR What is the way to get .stl files for collision of links of robot (ABB IRB4600)?

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS. I am trying to develop the URDF file for ABB IRB4600-60/2.05 robot but i am not understanding how to create collision models (meshes > collision (.stl files). Please let me know the way ..should i need to develop by own through CAD software ?

Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254996/does-any-body-has-the-support-package-(need-urdf-file)-for-abb-irb4600-60/2.05?-or-what-is-the-way-to-get-.stl-files-for-collision-of-links-of-robot-(abb-irb4600)?/) by [Muneeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29399/muneeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Creating collision meshes is relatively simple: in most ROS description or ROS-Industrial support packages they are simple the *convex hulls* of the normal (or `visual`) messages.

You can create convex hulls using a nr of meshing tools. Two frequently used ones are Meshlab and Blender.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Muneeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29399/muneeb/) on 2017-02-21**:
Thanks for your response ..It is quite simple by using convex hull option in meshlab tool ..
One can find 'convex hull' option in meshlab   (Filters > Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstructiion > convex hull)